# I try to install PostgreSQL-10.4-1

Tags: postgresql, windows, installation

I try to install PostgreSQL-10.4-1 and it shows me this message : "There has been an error. Error with configuration or permissions. Please see log file for more information"

install PostgreSQL-10.4-1-win64-bigsql (possibly a cracked version)

Comment: Why are you trying to install an [outdated and unsupported version](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Comment: I don't believe [BigSQL](http://www.bigsql.org/) exists anymore as the link resolves to 'Server Not Found'. I would try a current supported version(11-15) from the community site [Download](https://www.postgresql.org/download/).